# token from localStorage is undefined react

Tags: reactjs

**Navbar.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const Navbar = () => {
    let history = useHistory()
    let token = ''

    const logout = () => {
        window.localStorage.removeItem('token')
        history.push('/login')
    }
    
    // token is b33b1e262013d445bd0dd83314def8b825f27e17 
    setInterval(token = window.localStorage.getItem('token'), 2000)

    return (
        <nav>
            <div className='nav-content'>
                <h1>LunCare <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h1>   

                {
                window.localStorage.getItem('token') ?
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#' onClick={logout}>Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
                :
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href=''>Register</a>
                        <a href='/login'>Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
                }
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

> All I want to do is to check the local storage for a token if it's available, and when it finds it the token is for some reason undefined, I tried converting it to a string but that causes other problems too... any help is appreciated.

Comment: is the token actually there when you check your localstorage in browser? At what point do you set it?

Comment: its there the whole time, unless i click logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are accessing token inside setInterval is wrong. setInterval accepts a callback function as the first parameter.

This is how you have to use it.

```
setInterval(() => token = window.localStorage.getItem('token') , 2000);
```

But , on a side note, it is not a good practice to access a token like this. Why do you want to read it every 2 seconds? If you can explain the scenario, I can suggest better ways to achieve the same.